# What is the length that is covered by all positive integers on the circle?

Tags: circles, integers

Suppose we have a circle with radius `r=1` and suppose we start marking on the circle all positive integers (lets suppose that `0` is also positive) with interval `1` (`1rad`). It's trivial to see that this way no two integers overlap - we can mark on the circle all positive integers up to the infinity and only part of the circle will be covered by integers - dots that represent certain integer.

My question is: What is the length that is covered by dots on the circle?

Comment: Define "length".

Comment: That length would be zero with respect to the usual one-dimensional measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure, which is actually an outer measure) because it is the countable union of null sets (points).

Comment: @KennyLau We have covered circle with dots as mentioned in a question. Under length i mean the length of the part of the circle that is marked by points. Or I want to now what ratio of the circle is covered by dots

Comment: @blindProgrammer you still have to define length.

Comment: Look up "measure theory".

Comment: @blindProgrammer: The dots will be all over (which would require a definition if we were to go anywhere with this) the circle, but make a totally disconnected (another term that could use a definition) set for which length has no intuitive meaning. That's why people ask you to define length. Your question is (with apropriate definitions) equivalent to asking about the length of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.